# Mouse and keyboard not getting captured by Xephyr

Tags: x11, keyboard, mouse, xephyr

So, I started a Xephyr window: `Xephyr -br -ac -noreset -screen 1280x720 :1` and then started xfce4 inside of that Xephyr X server:

```
Export DISPLAY=:1
startxfce4
```

This all works fine, but now I want to get my cursor and mouse inside of that Xephyr X server...

According to the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xephyr), you are apparently supposed to be able to capture user input by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> when the window is in focus. But, on my machine, this doesn't actually seem to do anything. So I was wondering if I am doing something wrong here?

Also, I can't find anything about this keyboard combo in the manpage, does Xephyr have any documentation that covers stuff like hotkeys?

Comment: Looking into the same issue now. Starting xephyr with sudo helps it get keyboard and mouse correctly, but of course it is not desirable. Have you managed to solve this quest?

Answer (score 2):

For Xephyr 21.1.3 - 21.1.6 (e.g. xserver-xephyr 2:21.1.3, Ubuntu 22.04.1) `unset XDG_SEAT` to make input devices work again:

```
unset XDG_SEAT
Xephyr -br -ac -noreset -screen 1280x800 :2
```

Mouse and keyboard devices as well as capturing input with `Ctrl+Shift` should work after that.

There is an open issue (#1289) about this in [freedesktop.org's GitLab](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/issues/1289).